# Does 'to mend cars' sound well?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

I wonder if the usage of *mend* regarding cars is okay. There were some discussions on other sites, but there is not a really clear answer. So, is it okay to say 'This guy mends cars' (this is his profession) or one risks sounding like a grandad?

Comment: Related at ELL: *[repair, fix or mend](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/120538)*

Answer (score 3):

You would be understood, but it doesn’t really collocate. It doesn’t show  up in [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) under a search for `MEND  _nn*` where the latter term matches nouns. That search (grouped by lemma) gives these results:

[image]

Note that “mend fences” is mostly the idiomatic expression. Thus I would say that “mend” is mostly used with fixing things figuratively and literally when repairing clothing.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion *mend* is a really antique word and nowadays it is only (rarely) used when speaking about one's health: for example doctors can mend a patient's condition. So I would leave this word out in this sentence.

Comment: I have heard very old, very upper-class British people say 'mend' in relation to repair of appliances, cars, etc. It is old-fashioned to say the least. It still has a use in connection with repairing simple objects, e.g. you could mend a broken plate by gluing the pieces together.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Conversely, I think of it as a rather childish expression (when applied to complex machinery, not broken plates).

Comment: @Kate Bunting - I don't know about that. I saw it as old fashioned, mainly. Older upper class people, in my youth, had grown up in an age of less complex technology, and most things could be "mended" (by a "workman" usually).

Comment: One would still 'mend' a tear, rip or cut in paper or cloth; there are shops where I live offering 'invisible mending' of damaged clothing.

Answer (score -2):

'mend' that word is really rare nowadays like @tyler1 said. Btw mend cars? it sounds bit wrong(ish). Can you please provide us a usage? like for schools, or office usage. i would better recommend-

> This guy fixes cars
>
> This guy repairs cars
>
> This guy services cars

for a bit fancy usage see- (caution while using these)-

> This guy revives back cars  (i read this in a book)
>
> This guy reconstructs cars

Yes, mend is a synonym of repair but it seems that it is not good here, so better dont use the word-"mend" in this sentence.

Comment: Here it is, but I do not say that this source is good :) https://books.google.ru/books?id=nttLDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA231&lpg=PA231&dq=mending+cars&source=bl&ots=EU1wma5pk3&sig=TOvnFW2lk49x1i2cHrzwhvq3l2M&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinqrjMu8DfAhWmqIsKHbg8B_UQ6AEwDXoECAEQAQ